# Gremlin : Checking existence in traversal step or set

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop

### Background:

I am trying to run a search through a graph and change the search behavior based on if the discovered node belongs to a pre-defined set available before the query is executed.

I can't find any documentation on how to cross-check if a vertex or attribute is present in a set in gremlin.

### Examples:

Given: `g.V('id1', 'id2', 'id3').as('a')`

Find: if `a` includes `'id4'`

OR

Given: `g.V('id1', 'id2', 'id3').fold().store('a') => ['id1', 'id2', 'id3']`

Find: if `a` contains `id4`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to approach this is to use the `coalesce` step. Here is a simple example from the Gremlin Console.

```java
gremlin> g.V(1,2,3).fold().as('found').V(3).coalesce(where(within('found')).constant('found'),constant('not found'))
==>found

gremlin> g.V(1,2,3).fold().as('found').V(4).coalesce(where(within('found')).constant('found'),constant('not found'))
==>not found
```